# Python modulus result is incorrect for some reason?

Tags: python-3.x

Python modulus result is incorrect:

```
363.12 % 7.12
  7.119999999999999
```

The result should be 0. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine."

by Python Docs: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer